# append data in div through jQuery [not Woking]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

I want to append selectbox and textbox in div but my code is not working. I tried my end and learn other threads code but the same I could not achieve the goal.
here I show the single one main div where I am appending the data but in my real case I have dynamic `<div class="note" id="23203">` that's why I mention `div id` which is unique.

I want to append the textbox and select box in `appendApp_body` when I click `+`  button and same remove the div if I click to select `-` div button

Please help me how to make it correct.

I want when I click the button

```js
var xMachine = 1;

$('.add_MoreMachine__button').click(function() {
  var qty = $(this).attr("data-qty");
  var maxMachineField = qty;
  if (xMachine < maxMachineField) {
    newrowMachine = '<div class="appendApp_body"><select class="custom-select font-size-sm shadow-none" name="product_name[]"><option>--</option><option>6 AMP (RF)</option></select ><input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="productnumber[]" /></div><button type="button" class = "btn btn-danger btn-circle float-right remove_Machinebutton" ><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button ></div>';
    $('.appendApp_body:last').after(newrowMachine);
  } else {
    alert("Ops...! You have total " + maxMachineField + " allowed fields to fill and now you don't have extra permission to proceed this action. [error: limit-reached]");
    return false;
  }
});


$(".complaint_MachineFor4").on("click", ".remove_Machinebutton", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).closest('<div>').remove();
                    xMachine--;
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="note" id="23203">
  <div class="note-body">
    <div class="note-added-on">
      <select style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="custom-select font-size-sm shadow-none" name="product_id[]">
        <option value="Issue1">Issue1</option>
      </select>
      <div class="appendApp_body">
        <select class="custom-select font-size-sm shadow-none" name="product_name[]">
          <option selected="" value="0">--</option>
          <option>6 AMP (RF)</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="productnumber[]" />
      </div>

      <button style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-success add_MoreMachine__button" data-qty="2"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are mutliple `notes` divs you can use  `$(this).closest(".note-added-on")..` to append generated divs only where button has been clicked. Then , to remove same you can use `$(this).prev('.appendApp_body').remove()` to remove `appendApp_body` div and `$(this).remove()` to remove button as well.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.add_MoreMachine__button').click(function() {
  var xMachine = $(this).closest('.note-added-on').find('.appendApp_body').length; //get length of cloned div
  var maxMachineField = $(this).attr("data-qty");
  //compare
  if (xMachine < maxMachineField) {
    //just add one extra class..`cloned..`
    newrowMachine = '<div class="appendApp_body cloned"><select class="custom-select font-size-sm shadow-none" name="product_name[]"><option>--</option><option>6 AMP (RF)</option></select ><input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="productnumber[]" /></div><button type="button" class = "btn btn-danger btn-circle float-right remove_Machinebutton" ><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></div>';
    //append inside `note-added-on` div 
    $(this).closest(".note-added-on").append(newrowMachine);
  } else {
    alert("Ops...! You have total " + maxMachineField + " allowed fields to fill and now you don't have extra permission to proceed this action. [error: limit-reached]");
    return false;
  }
});


$(document).on("click", ".remove_Machinebutton", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).prev('.appendApp_body').remove(); //get prev div
  $(this).remove(); //remove button as well
});
```

```css
.note {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="note" id="23203">
  <div class="note-body">
    <div class="note-added-on">
      <select style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="custom-select font-size-sm shadow-none" name="product_id[]">
        <option value="Issue1">Issue1</option>
      </select>
      <div class="appendApp_body">
        <select class="custom-select font-size-sm shadow-none" name="product_name[]">
          <option selected="" value="0">--</option>
          <option>6 AMP (RF)</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="productnumber[]" />
      </div>

      <button style="margin-top: 10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-success add_MoreMachine__button" data-qty="2"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="note" id="232031">
  <div class="note-body">
    <div class="note-added-on">
      <select style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="custom-select font-size-sm shadow-none" name="product_id[]">
        <option value="Issue1">Issue1</option>
      </select>
      <div class="appendApp_body">
        <select class="custom-select font-size-sm shadow-none" name="product_name[]">
          <option selected="" value="0">--</option>
          <option>6 AMP (RF)</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="productnumber[]" />
      </div>

      <button style="margin-top: 10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-success add_MoreMachine__button" data-qty="1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to make `xMachine` by default `1`...if `data-qty="1"` then not append next textbox.. Please help and understand me

Comment: Just change `cloned` to `appendApp_body` added that as well in updated code . Let  me know if this is what you need .

Comment: I want to append if `data-qty` above `1`..because `1` div area is already exist.....

actually I submit all data with ajax... if possibe then add a form also where if we click one button then all input daa will send via ajax...

Comment: How many div you need to append depending on data-qty ? If yes above answer will work fine  . Also , about ajax you can ask another question and if above answer is helpful you can upvote and accept it .

Comment: can I ask another question for ajax for this form there will you help me ? your current answer was really helpful

Comment: I wish to append the elements above the `Plus [+] Button` means `Plus` always below appended elements how we do that pls update it possible, it takes less than a minute you want.. sir pls help

Comment: Instead of `$(this).closest(".note-added-on").append(newrowMachine);` use `$(newrowMachine).insertBefore($(this))`